# Unable to save file with ASP.NET FileUpload - access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to upload the a file through the asp.net FileUpload control. However, as soon as I click the button to upload the file it shows the error

> "Access to the path 'G:\Files' is denied.".

The code is

```
 if (btnFileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {

              btnFileUpload.SaveAs(@"G:\Files");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Anyone can help me out.

Comment: Hello, can you please post your code on how you save the file?

Comment: Make sure your application has access to the drive you are saving the file.

Comment: Check if `IUSR` has permission on the directory. You can also check for `IIS_IUSRS`'s permission.

Comment: Can you try adding the file name ? i.e. G:\files\abc.txt

Comment: Thanks. I passed the file name at the end     btnFileUpload.SaveAs(@"G:\Files\" + btnFileUpload.FileName);